# Iterating through a dictionary within an array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to iterate through a dictionary within an array. Said array was returned by an API. I can access the dictionary like so:

```
poll_session['Itineraries'][0]['PricingOptions'][0]['Price']
```

I would like to access each `['Price']` under `['PricingOptions']`.

I have been unable to use `.iteritems()` or a for loop to get each `['Price']`.

A collapsed version of the dict looks like this.

```
[
   "Itineraries": [
                     "PricingOptions" [
                                          "Price": 427.35
                  ]
        ]
]
```

The expected result would be an array with all the prices:

Example:

```
['647.90', '990.12', '345.40']
```

Comment: If you got one Price (427.35) how is it supposed to collect your desired list ?

Comment: Can you provide some minimum and complete sample? For starters, your dict is **not** a valid `dict`.

Comment: Can't you do something like `[dct['price'] for dct in poll_session['Itineraries'][0]['PricingOptions']]`?

Comment: please provide a complete sample of your dict. your current sample is not a valid dict, it's like array but not really an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python3.* you can try the below code

```
poll_session = {
   "Itineraries": [{"PricingOptions": [{"Price": 427.35},{"Price": 427.35}]}]
}



full_price_list = []
for each_pricing_option_array in poll_session["Itineraries"]:
    for each_price_object in each_pricing_option_array["PricingOptions"]:
        full_price_list.append(each_price_object["Price"])


print (full_price_list)
```

Comment: This did exactly what I needed. No modification necessary. Sorry for the poorly worded question (wrote it functioning on 4 hours of sleep), but you understood exactly what I meant

Answer (score 1):

If the price is an array, then you can do something like this -

```
myPriceArray = {
   "Itineraries":{
            "PricingOptions":{
                "Price": [427.35,437.35,447.35]
            }
    }
}
print(myPriceArray['Itineraries']['PricingOptions']['Price'])
for singlePrice in myPriceArray['Itineraries']['PricingOptions']['Price']: 
    print(singlePrice)
```

However if that is not what you want, please update the myPriceArray and then I'll share the solution accordingly.

Or if Itineraries is an array, then something like this can be done -

```
myPriceObject = {
   "Itineraries":[
            {
            "PricingOptions":{
                    "Price": 427.35
                }
            },
            {
            "PricingOptions":{
                    "Price": 437.35
                }
            },
            {
            "PricingOptions":{
                   "Price": 447.35
                }
            }
        ]
    }

for Itinerary in myPriceObject['Itineraries']: 
    print(Itinerary['PricingOptions']['Price'])
```